# Is there any way to poll any change in amazon products?

Tags: amazon-mws

Is there any possibility to get information about change in listings from Amazon. Like I would like to get the listings which are changed on amazon.

Comment: Simply repeatedly query the same listing. After the first query, cache the response, and then check whether the subsequent response is equal to what was cached.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an ever better option for what you are asking. MWS has the [Subscriptions API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?group=subscriptions&section=subscriptions) which will send you a notification when certain things about an item change rather than having to query the items and log differences yourself.

You can get [notifications](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/subscriptions/Subscriptions_NotificationType.html) on things such as:

- AnyOfferChanged - When any of the top 20 offers (prices) on the item changes
- FulfillmentOrderStatus - This one is interesting as you can get notificaitons on fulfillment of the item (i.e. when item comes back in stock, when it is on the way, when a shipper has a planned order, etc)
- FeePromotion - When an item gets a promotional price (lightning deal, etc)

Comment: This will only get if there is any offers changed. But I would like to get notifications if there is any change in the Amazon inventory.